# How do I extract the file names from an "upload file" component and display them in a list on the UI?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, promise

I'm creating a form for users to be able to upload files from the frontend directly into an AWS S3 bucket and have gotten this to work ok and console.log the "data" to show this.

[image]

What I want to do is then extract the name of the file (key) from the data and display each file name in an array with useState (in this case [fileInfos, setFilesInfos]) and map through this array to display each file name in a list in the UI.

The problem is I don't know how to extract the filename from the "data" and store it in the array to start with. Here is my code so far:

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import S3 from 'react-aws-s3';

const Upload = () => {
  const fileInput = useRef();

  const [selectedFiles, setSelectedFiles] = useState(undefined);
  const [currentFile, setCurrentFile] = useState(undefined);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const [fileInfos, setFileInfos] = useState([]);

  const config = {
    bucketName: process.env.REACT_APP_BUCKET_NAME,
    region: process.env.REACT_APP_REGION,
    accessKeyId: process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESS_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.REACT_APP_ACCESS_KEY,
  };

  const selectFile = (e) => {
    setSelectedFiles(e.target.files);
    // console.log(selectedFiles);
  };

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let newArr = fileInput.current.files;
    for (let i = 0; i < newArr.length; i++) {
      handleUpload(newArr[i]);
      // console.log(newArr);
    }
  };

  const handleUpload = (file) => {
    let newFileName = file.name;
    const ReactS3Client = new S3(config);
    ReactS3Client.uploadFile(file, newFileName).then((data) => {
      if (data.status === 204) {
        console.log(data);
      } else {
        console.log('fail');
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form className='' onSubmit={handleClick}>
        {currentFile && (
          <div className='progress'>
            <div
              className='progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped'
              role='progressbar'
              aria-valuenow={progress}
              aria-valuemin='0'
              aria-valuemax='100'
              style={{ width: progress + '%' }}
            >
              {progress}%
            </div>
          </div>
        )}

        <label className='btn btn-default'>
          Choose Files
          <input type='file' onChange={selectFile} multiple ref={fileInput} />
        </label>

        <br />
        <button className='btn btn-success' disabled={!selectedFiles} type='submit' onClick={handleUpload}>
          Upload
        </button>

        <div className='alert alert-light' role='alert'>
          {message}
        </div>

        <div className='card'>
          <div className='card-header'>List of Files</div>
          <ul className='list-group'>
            {fileInfos &&
              fileInfos.map((file, index) => (
                <li className='list-group-item' key={index}>
                  <a href={file.url}>{file.name}</a>
                </li>
              ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Upload;
```

The main problem I'm having is here: How do I then take the "key" out of data and set it to "fileInfos" so it's stored in my state?

[image]

[image]

I want to be able to display it like so in my return below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have the 'data' object, you can just extract it and append it to your fileInfos. So if I understand your problem correctly, you could do something like this:

```js
if (data.status === 204) {
   console.log(data);
   const fileName = data.key; // <-- gets the value of 'key'.

   // now store it with the previous names
   let prevValues = [...fileInfos];
   prevValues.push(fileName);

   // set the new values
   setFileInfos(prevValues);
}
```

This however only stores the names. So in your render method, change
`<p>{file.name}</p>` to `<p>{file}</p>`

Comment: Thank you so much, the only thing that confuses me now is that despite mapping through fileInfos, only the last file's name actually displays in the UI regardless of if I'm uploading more than 1

Comment: I'm not sure how Amazon buckets work but I think your `ReactS3Client.uploadFile()` will only be run once. Does the response `data` perhaps contain an array of uploaded files?

Comment: I managed to get this working the way I wanted yesterday, so thanks so much for your help. I'm now trying to get a list of all the files stored in the bucket and display them in the UI